# KDE's gui network manager can't connect to DSL using pppoe

Tags: kubuntu, kde, pppoe, dsl

I've tryed many linux distros with KDE (deb/rpm-based), there are always this problem. I have not a modem. There is no problem with connection with pppoeconf, but I wish do it using GUI. Would also good to know why KDE developers can't solve this problem for many years.

Answer (score 0):

if you are complaining about kde daemon asking for password, this should solve your problem :

go to your configured DSL connection.
under general tab,

just below "automatically connect to this network......."

CHECK "all users may connect to this network".

Doing this solved my dsl problem in kubuntu 14.04.3. it won't show kde daemon asking for password anymore.

Comment: no, it just can't establish connection.